# How to combine log exception from multiple lines to one line

Tags: batch-file, awk, sed, tr

I have a log file with exceptions where the exception is on separate lines. I'd like to get sed/awk/cut to combine them on one like. Rules. The start of the first line always has a date time stamp.

Example: (exception on 5 lines)

```
2017-04-24T04:26:58.728-0400 - VALUE {tomcat-device-http-1} none|none 
[{{0ecfe8a7}{Uri, - WARN Could not marshal entity
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at com.sun..java:487)
    at com.sun:323)
    at com.sun.java:251)
```

End result:

```
2017-04-24T04:26:58.728-0400 - VALUE {tomcat-device-http-1} none|none [{{0ecfe8a7}{Uri, - WARN Could not marshal entity java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 at com.sun..java:487) at com.sun:323) at com.sun.java:251)
```

Comment: Nothing else starts with a date-time stamp?

Comment: The [batch-file] tag seems wrong as the tools (awk,sed,tr) aren't usually present in a windows environment.

Comment: Are you running on DOS, or in a Windows command-line terminal?  Are you sure you want it all on one line — even when there are a hundred levels in the stack trace (which is what I tend to see in Java stack traces).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a simple and efficient (fast) solution using [JREPL.BAT - a regular expression text processor](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044). JREPL.BAT is pure script (hybrid batch/JScript) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward - No 3rd party exe file required.

The following will work directly from the command line, no batch file required.

If log file test.log already exists and you want to see the output on the screen, then:

```
jrepl "^(?:(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d{3}-\d{4} -)|\s*)(.*)" "stdout.write(($1?'\n'+$1:'  ')+$2);$txt=false" /jmatchq /f test.log
```

If you want to write the results to file "output.log", then append `/o output.log`

If you want to overwrite the original file, then append `/o -`

If you want to put the command in a batch script, then use `call jrepl`

If you have a program that writes the log to stdout, then you can pipe the program output to the command and drop the `/f` option.

```
logGeneratingCommand | jrepl "^(?:(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d{3}-\d{4} -)|\s*)(.*)" "stdout.write(($1?'\n'+$1:'  ')+$2);$txt=false" /jmatchq
```

Obviously you can add the `/o outfile` or `/o -` option.

`CALL` is not required in the batch script when you use a pipe.

Full JREPL documentation is available from the command line via `jrepl /?`, or `jrepl /??` for paged help. A summarized list of options is available via `jrepl /?options`. Use `jrepl /?help` for a complete list of all HELP options.